# Can't get view id while iterating through a list of all views

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, hashmap, android-view

I have a simple group of dynamically generated EditText fields with their respective labels, and I'm trying to get the IDs of them to save data by iterating through all the views in the parent layout. My (simplified) code is:

```
int layoutChildren = linearLayout.getChildChildCount();

if(layoutChildren > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < layoutChildren; i++){
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

        if(v instanceof EditText){
            // This is returning -1
            int ID = ((EditText)v).getId();
        }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
int ID = v.getId();
```

and

```
EditText textObject = (EditText)v;
int ID = textObject.getId();
```

I know that the EditText object in question has an id, because if I call getId on it immediately after creation, it does not return -1, yet it does not appear to work while iterating through all views. Is there a fix or workaround to this? I'm also curious to know why this method isn't working, as I'm new to android development after working in java for a time, and am curious if this is caused by some sort of missing knowledge of android behaviors.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The code that generates the views and IDs was requested: it is simply

```
EditText rb = new EditText(this);
// Field ID list is a hashmap of unique integer IDs with string keys
rb.setId(fieldIDList.get("byField"));
linearLayout.addView(rb);
// This is a test variable that confirms the ID has been set in debugging
int testVar = rb.getId();
```

I suppose it might be possible to maintain a list of created fields and access them that way, but the code would not be as clean and I'm personally curious as to why the above method isn't working.

Comment: `dynamically generated EditText`. Post the code where you generate the view's and set the ids.

Comment: Did you try using via findViewById?

Comment: may be you are calling it before creating the view... Are you using it in fragment?

Comment: @WanaAnt I'm trying to get the view id, not find it.

Comment: @sourabhbans I've checked, it is being used in a fragment but the code is attached to a next button as error handling before any of the views or layouts get cleaned up. Can confirm views are there; the code has error handling for that which I excluded from the example.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
private List<View> getAllChildrens(View v) {
        List<View> visited = new ArrayList<View>();
        List<View> unvisited = new ArrayList<View>();
        unvisited.add(v);

        while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
            View child = unvisited.remove(0);
            visited.add(child);
            if (!(child instanceof ViewGroup)) continue;
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) child;
            final int childCount = group.getChildCount();
            for (int i=0; i<childCount; i++) unvisited.add(group.getChildAt(i));
        }

        return visited;
    }
```

and iterate it as ..

```
   for(View view : getAllChildrens(view_grp)){
                 Log.e("View", ""+view.getTag() +" id : "+view.getId());
             }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do; it just looks like a more complicated version of the loop I'm using, but is still using the same method to get the ID. Could you explain?

Comment: in above method... it is filtering view groups and all its child views... Can you give it a try...??

Comment: That is already done with `if(v instanceof EditText)` but I can attempt it

Comment: also take care of the instance of your parent layout... that u r using the correct instance of your linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by an oversight in my own code: I had forgotten to assign an ID to a date field that was an EditText object set to accept no input, which was causing the -1 return value. Assigning an ID to this field solved the issue.

Apologies to anyone reading the question, as it was not solvable using the information provided. Perhaps it is best to include an error handling check for when an ID returns this value, and print information about the View to console.